# How to count the number of consecutive numbers in a data.frame?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I'm using R programming btw.

So say I have a data frame like this.

```
        row.names   Tx    Hx     Tn
1        51        33.9  43.48  24.9
2        52        33.0  41.03  22.5
3        64        32.8  37.74  23.3
4        65        32.7  44.53  22.3
5        66        34.9  42.43  23.5
6        77        33.6  38.74  21.8
7        78        34.6  45.46  27.1
8        84        32.9  41.67  24.1
9        85        35.1  43.15  25.0
10      117        32.0  37.11  20.0
```

I'm trying to figure out how many times two or more consective numbers and three or more consective nummbers occur in the column row.names.

So for this example 51, 52 then 64, 65, 66 then 77, 78 and lastly 84, 85. I just want a count for how many times this happens for two or more consective numbers and three or more consective numbers.

My result would be

```
2+ = 4
3+ = 1
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Try `cumsum(rev(table(table(cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(df$row.names)!=1))))))`

Comment: See, also, `seqle` from "cgwtools" package: `cgwtools::seqle(DF$row.names)`; then, you can apply `table` for each ">= n" you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tmp <- table(rle(cumsum(c(1L, diff(DF$row.names)) != 1L))$lengths)
cumsum(rev(tmp))
#3 2 1 
#1 4 5
```

Comment: @Nick Driscoll It does work for the example you provided.  If it doesn't work, you should give more details.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a helpful comment. Consider providing your data as `dput` output as this is most likely a data format issue. E.g., you might need `as.integer(DF$row.names)`.

Comment: Why did you accept it as an answer if it doesn't work?

Comment: Because row.names was class NULL and once I changed it to integer it worked :)

Comment: Class `NULL` means they don't exist. But glad you were able to sort this out (however you managed to do that).

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this, until I saw @akrun's comment.  I started there and made some modifications.  This works:

```
df <- structure(list(
    row.names = c(51L, 52L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 77L, 78L, 84L, 85L, 117L), 
    Tx = c(33.9, 33, 32.8, 32.7, 34.9, 33.6, 34.6, 32.9, 35.1, 32), 
    Hx = c(43.48, 41.03, 37.74, 44.53, 42.43, 38.74, 45.46, 41.67, 43.15, 37.11), 
    Tn = c(24.9, 22.5, 23.3, 22.3, 23.5, 21.8, 27.1, 24.1, 25, 20)), 
    .Names = c("row.names", "Tx", "Hx", "Tn"), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))

delta <- c(0, diff(df$row.names))
tally <- cumsum(delta!=1)
count <- table(table(tally[delta==1])+1)
twoplus <- sum(count[names(count) > 1.999])
threeplus <- sum(count[names(count) > 2.999])
twoplus
threeplus
```